# Should we duplicate part of an existing partial answer or edit it to include more information?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

I had a programming problem involving SQL, and I found this question that corresponded to my issue: *[MySQL Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16969060)*.

On that question I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41603128/10952503) that talks about where the issue stems from, but as it doesn't explain how to fix it, **I consider it a partial answer to the question**.

In my case, I used the information provided in the answer to solve my problem, so I know how to improve the answer to include the rest of the solution.

However, when I clicked on "Post an answer," Stack Overflow alerted me about the high number of answers to that question (31).

So, instead of making a duplicate answer, I [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30147410) that took a long time to be reviewed. The objective of this edit was to **add more information** and thus make the answer **more complete**.

I was really afraid this edit would get rejected, which is why in my edit summary I said, "Instead of adding new answer."

My edit was **rejected** on the grounds that it **does not respect the original author**.

Should I make a new answer? Post a comment under the existing answer adding the missing detail? Or was I right to edit it, and if so, could someone approve it?

---

As suggest by the message on the suggested edit, I made a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69759918/10952503). But, few hours ago, someone alert me about the duplicate answer thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969060/mysql-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint/41603128#comment123310793_69759918). So, I link this meta post to explain why I made this new answer that is not only a duplicate.

But this comment confused me :

- The original answer is a partial to me: need update to be more useful
- I edit the answer to add details: rejected because should be an answer
- I answer: not well received because it's a duplicate

Should I keep the answer? Should we approve the previous suggested edit?

Comment: What do you mean by *"Such as I find the answer partially, and I would like to share it."*, *"Also, so tell me there is more than 30 answers."*, and *"Such as I fix my issue, but I know how to fix it."* (close to incomprehensible)? For example, for the second, did someone else tell you there were more than 30 answers? - *"Also, someone told me there were more than 30 answers."* Or is *"so"* really *"SO"* (for *"Stack Overflow"*)? Or something else?

Comment: So is for StackOverflow. I get an alert to tell that there is lot of answers. Sorry if it's not easy to understand. The answer that I find just say "The issue is made by..." but don't say how to fix it. But i will edit my question to make it easier to understand

Comment: I don't understand why this need details. Can someone explain ? I already tell the actual state, what I did and I well ask a question about how to explain how to solve the question

Comment: This post makes sense to me ... they found an old answer that they considered partial or incomplete, tried to edit more info into the answer and it was declined. Now, they are wondering if it was better to make a new answer, despite the post already having 31 answers and this new answer will be a partial duplicate of the previous incomplete answer

Comment: if it were me I would've just left a comment expanding on the old answer.

Comment: That's exactly this @Vultuxe ! And that's à good idea to left comment, I didn't think about this

Comment: That's the description of the rejected edit. *"It should have been written as a comment or an answer."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a good question because it's something we do see a lot of. I like to call them "late retreads", because we're going over a previous answer again.

Let's compare. Here's the [answer that's older](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41603128)

> Check for table compatibility.  For example, if one table is `MyISAM` and the other one is `InnoDB`, you may have this issue.

And here's your extended answer (formatting doesn't do as well in blockquotes)

> For me, the issue comes from table compatibility with engine.
> You can check it with `SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'tableName'`.
> For example, if one table is `MyISAM` and the other one is `InnoDB`, you may have this issue.
> You can change it thanks to this command:
> `ALTER TABLE myTable ENGINE = InnoDB;`
> [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html)

I appreciate your willingness to enumerate this, but, as the comment mentioned, it doesn't add anything new. The TL;DR answer is "Make sure your tables use the same engine". That does raise a couple of other questions...

1. [How can I check MySQL engine type for a specific table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213543/how-can-i-check-mysql-engine-type-for-a-specific-table)
2. [How to change the storage engine type on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780083/how-to-change-the-storage-engine-type-on-mysql)

Is the problem with late retreads clearer now? You gave us those two steps in your answer... but each has been answered elsewhere. In other words, the existing answers are sufficient to point you in the direction of still other questions that explain how to check the table engine and change it if necessary. If your answer were the first one posted, enumerating this would be fine. And, to your credit, you did suggest an edit first. The reviewers were correct in rejecting it, because you did make significant changes to the answer (we don't expect reviewers to understand a subject to review it).

To that end, I've done a couple of things

1. I deleted your answer. There were too many other answers retreading territory I pruned as well. That's why you get a warning in trying to add another answer
2. I overrode the edit rejection purely on moderator prerogative. You did leave the original post as-is and added the extra info around it. Since it does add some value there for people finding the post, I think it's useful. Understand that I took this action only because we fleshed it out here on Meta. We generally expect reviewers to reject edits like that and if you suggest other edits like that they are highly likely to be declined. This is not some sort of new exception to edit reviewing.

Comment: Thanks you ! That's perfect. My way was mainly to add docs & command in the "This is why you get the issue" and keep time to don't have to make some search, just use cmd. That's why -for me- it add something. But thanks for all clarification, details and changes !